# Tracing execution of an Ada program

Tags: ada, gnat

Does Ada/GNAT supports something like the automatic tracing of the execution of a program (or selected packages/procedures/functions) for debug purposes? I am not interested in a logger package.

Imagine working on a real old Ada project and using a debugger to step through the code is not an option. In my opinion adding text outputs often helps to understand the code:

```ada
if A and B or C then
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("1");

   [...]
else
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("2");

   [...]
end if;
```

But adding such text outputs is a manual process and it takes time to do it on complex code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to have a look at [rr](https://rr-project.org/). I've never used it myself, but it might very well work with Ada.

Comment: It indeed works. Nifty tool! Any good gdb frontend to use with?

Comment: @Álex: Nice! Can't help you with a front-end, but some people seem to use their IDE (see [rr wiki](https://github.com/mozilla/rr/wiki/Using-rr-in-an-IDE)). Maybe you could use the `gdb` interface of GPS.

Comment: @Álex: You could try to connect to the `gdbserver` interface exposed by `rr replay` from the GPS IDE "Debugger Console" (see also the [GNAT UG](https://docs.adacore.com/gnat_ugn-docs/html/gnat_ugn/gnat_ugn/gnat_and_program_execution.html#remote-debugging-with-gdbserver)).

Comment: Thanks, @DeeDee, I will try that.

Comment: Is `rr` limited to a Linux based operating system? Alternatives for Windows?

Comment: @Marcello90: It seems that `rr` is Linux only and no viable Windows alternative exists at the time of writing. Microsoft did create an equivalent functionality for Windows named ["Time Travel Debugging"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/time-travel-debugging-overview) (which is part of WinDbg Preview), but I'm afraid that WinDbg cannot be used in this case. WinDbg requires a different (proprietary) file format for debugging symbols ([PDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_database)) which isn't supported by GCC.